# Magento Showing error in connecting with market-place.

Tags: magento2, php, extensions

I am using Magento 2.0.15 while connecting with the Magento-Marketplace with the private & Public key for installing the extension in to my Magento It is showing below error

> Failed to connect to repo.magento.com port 443: Connection timed out

Any help?

Comment: Is it an error due to some SSL issues ? or anything else as of my knowledge port no 443 is basically used for SSL.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this link may be it's helpfull to you:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/5239

Comment: No sir I think it is not that what I want!